# SMS verification message is not received on firebase verifyPhoneNumber

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Auth JS SDK. And everything works except for SMS Multi-factor Authentication.
I am on Spark billing plan. Billing account is connected.
Auth project with Identity Platform enabled.
Auth methods enabled:

- Email/Password
- Phone
  My real phone number added in the Phone numbers for testing list.

My code on sign up:

```
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(window.accountManager.auth, this.email, this.password).then((response) => {
    //some actions
}).then(async (response) => {
    const recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier("recaptcha-container", {
        "size": "invisible",
        "callback": function(response) {
            console.log(response); // (1)
        }
    }, window.accountManager.auth);
    const mfaSession = await multiFactor(window.accountManager.user).getSession();
    const phoneInfoOptions = {
        phoneNumber: '+972.......', //my real Israeli phone number 
        session: mfaSession
    };
    const phoneAuthProvider = new PhoneAuthProvider(window.accountManager.auth);
    phoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(phoneInfoOptions, recaptchaVerifier)
        .then(function (verificationId) {
            console.log(verificationId); // (2)
        });
});
```

The user is created,
the invisible captcha is passed (1),
The verifyPhoneNumber executed and call the callback (2).

But I do not receive an sms.
Tryed that flow on [FirebaseUI Demo](https://fir-ui-demo-84a6c.firebaseapp.com/) - it works with my phone number.

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing was that the phone number should not be on the test numbers list.
If you use it there then you should use the test code from the list.

Comment: Please mark this question as resolved if this resolved the issue